# ASP.net core web api: Using Facebook/Google OAuth access token for authentication

Tags: c#, angular, authentication, google-oauth, asp.net-core-webapi

For serveral days now I am trying to get OAuth authentication with Google and Facebook to work within my ASP.net core web api project.

**my current status is:**

- I have an ASP.net core Web Api project in which the users need to be authenticated
- I have an angular 2 web app which should use my web api (with authentication)
- I have an android app, which should use my web api (with authentication)

**my goal is:**

- Using Google/Facebook as OAuth providers for login
- later: adding own user accounts (probably with IdentityServer4)
- no need to redirect to a special login website (like the IdentityServer4 solution). Just hit the facebook/google button in the app, allow access, done!

In my android and angular app I am able to retrieve the access tokens from google/facebook. Now, I want to use the OAuth implicit flow, to authenticate the user on my web api, with the given access tokens (putting the tokens into the header as bearer token)

There is my problem: is there any genric way to do this easily? I do not want to use the facebook/google SDKs for this.

I have tried following:

- **using IdentityServer4**: With this I am able to login with facebook/google on my webapi, but there is need of a redirection to the IdentityServer4 login page. Is there any possible way of just hitting the google/fb-Button in my app and logging in, **without redirection to the identityServer login page?**
- **using the google/facebook authentication middleware** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/): But they are not validating my sent bearer token (tried countless ways to achieve proper validation). Is this even possible to use within the web api?
- trying to use **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer-Middleware** and putting in the necessary options for google/facebook by myself, but also not validating (aswell countless attempts)

In the last few days, I have tried so much possible solutions, that I am totally stuck and lost track of what I need to do to achieve this. At this point I have read nearly every asp.net web api oauth tutorial/stackoverflow entry but can't figure out how to use this in my case as I want. Most tutorials are just for mvc-Websites or using IdentityServer4 with the redirection to its login page.

Any suggestions or solutions? What am I missing?

Comment: For 3rd party authentication, I believe when page redirected back to you application (user is authenticated), HTTP request should contain authentication data. You can write a global filter to intercept it. Check some details here: https://andrewlock.net/an-introduction-to-oauth-2-using-facebook-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I found a solution (some weeks ago, forgot to update here):
On the auth endpoint of IdentityServer4 one can use a special parameter, to redirect immediatly to the website of the selected identity provider, without going through the login page of identityserver. As stated here http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/authorize.html
the idp:name_of_idp parameter within the acr_values redirects directly to the identity provider, which is what I wanted.

Comment: Did you find final solution?

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment, if found a solution. I used the "idp:name" field within the acr_values to skip the usage of the identityServer4 login page and redirecting directly to the provider

Comment: I've been struggling with this the whole weekend! So on your point 2, it's just not possible? I'll try using IdentityServer4 as per your solution but it seems strange that if it's not possible that it's not said somewhere!

Comment: @nicV: You mean "using the google/facebook authentication middleware" as my second point? I don't know if this is possible, but within my attemtps to get this working, I had no luck. With idv4 it is also not necessary to use the built in auth-middleware. you get it with idv4 out of the box with more functions. My problem was the immediate redirect, which i thought is not possible (so you have to go the way over the idv4-website everytime, but as mentioned above, I found an solution for this problem)

Comment: @Rul3r yes that is what I meant. The most luck I've had is finding this tutorial, but it's for Framework not Core. I just wanted to try this for fun so haven't had chance to try implementing something similar in Core: http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/

Comment: @nicV Thanks for suggesting the article, it does exactly what is asked in the question. And it works with .net core seamlessly.

Answer (score 18):

If I undertsand correctly, you already have your Facebook user token from Facebook SDK through your app.
Like you I couldn't find how to do it with an ASP.NET Core library / package. So I went back to basics. 
I just call a endpoint of my api with the Facebook token, check it against the Facebook graph api and if fine then I register the user (if required) and return my JWT token as if the user logged through a classical username / password path.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("api/authentication/FacebookLogin")]
public async Task<IActionResult> FacebookLogin([FromBody] FacebookToken facebookToken)
{
    //check token
    var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/") };
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"me?access_token={facebookToken.Token}&fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,age_range,birthday,gender,locale,picture");
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) return BadRequest();
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var facebookAccount = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookAccount>(result);

    //register if required
    var facebookUser = _context.FacebookUsers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == facebookAccount.Id);
    if (facebookUser == null)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser {UserName = facebookAccount.Name, Email = facebookAccount.Email};
        var result2 = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
        if (!result2.Succeeded) return BadRequest();
        facebookUser = new FacebookUser {Id = facebookAccount.Id, UserId = user.Id};
        _context.FacebookUsers.Add(facebookUser);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    //send bearer token
    return Ok(GetToken(facebookUser.UserId));
}
```

Comment: aren't you supposed to validate the access token you got with facebook's app secret against the authorisation provider first (federation to facebook,)?

Answer (score -2):

You have to copy the custom code available in this [article on medium](https://medium.com/mr-old-school/asp-net-google-and-facebook-external-logins-f0ba5d1b02f2?source=linkShare-731a7a4e9990-1531658345)

Creat a function in AccountController.cs

```
 private async Task<ExternalLoginInfo> AuthenticationManager_GetExternalLoginInfoAsync_WithExternalBearer()
```

And paste the code given in the article